# Error con secuencias SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Al intentar crear una secuencia en mi base de datos, me arroja un error. A continuación procederé a publicar el script y el error de la consulta:

```
create sequence seq_valorar
start with 300
increment by 1
minvalue 300
no maxvalue 
no cycle;

create sequence seq_val
start with 300
increment by 1
minvalue 300
no maxvalue 
no cycle;
```

> Error de SQL (343): Tipo de objeto desconocido 'sequence' utilizado en una instrucción CREATE, DROP o ALTER

Comment: Que version de SQL Server estás usando?

Comment: sql server 2008, olvide colocar ese dato

Comment: Según la documentación, `sequence` solo funciona a partir del 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la documentación, `secuence` solo funciona a partir de SQL Server 2012.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx